# how can taking advantage of Mule Lifecycle

Tags: annotations, mule, mule-studio

i am exercising Mule
i read [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Taking+Advantage+of+Mule+Lifecycle)

i want to try  this sample and i create a project and create  a java class in Mule Studio
after that i copied  this code:

```
package org.mule.module.twilio;   
import org.mule.api.annotations.Configurable; 
import org.mule.api.annotations.Module;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Processor; 
import org.mule.api.annotations.lifecycle.Start; 
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Optional; 
import org.mule.api.callback.HttpCallback;  
 @Module(name = "twilio") 
public class TwilioConnector {

    /**
     * The account sid to be used to connect to Twilio.
      */
     @Configurable
     private String accountSid;
     /**
      * The authentication token to be used to connect to Twilio
      */
     @Configurable
    private String authToken;

    private TwilioClient twilioClient;

     @Start
     public void createTwilioClient() {
         twilioClient = new TwilioClient(accountSid, authToken);
     } 
   }
```

but i have a lot of error:
  all

```
The import org.mule.api.annotations.Configurable cannot be resolved
The import org.mule.api.annotations.Module cannot be resolved
The import org.mule.api.annotations.Processor cannot be resolved
The import org.mule.api.annotations.lifecycle cannot be resolved
The import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Optional cannot be resolved
The import org.mule.api.callback cannot be resolved
```

all clsaa imports are not knew
near  all annotation is: Configurable cannot be resolved to a type
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the [mule devkit annotation jar](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/tools/devkit/mule-devkit-annotations/3.3.0/) to your classpath?

Once you hava built your cloud connector you can add it to studio following the instruction available [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Your+First+Cloud+Connector)

Comment: I added 2libs 1-twilio-java-sdk-3.3.9.jar and 2-mule-devkit-annotations-3.3.0.jar i haven't any error .but I don't how to use this class. I added HTTP Endpoint and java component add configure java component with this class . but I had not any result. how can see result?

Comment: this subject is very big and difficult :(

Comment: What part do you find difficult? Maybe I can pion you out in the right direction.

Comment: can u explain relation to between Cloud Connector and use twilio class(my project)? for create cloud connector i did 1 step and wrote $ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.mule.tools.devkit \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=mule-devkit-archetype-cloud-connector \
 -DarchetypeVersion=3.3.1 -DgroupId=org.hello -DartifactId=hello-connector -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT ..... command prompt but i have error:'-DarchetypeRepository' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: MuleSoft already provide a twilio cloud connector (available here http://mulesoft.github.io/twilio-connector/mule/twilio-config.html). For this reason I was thinking your was an experiment to understand better how cloud connectors (i.e. project based on devkit) work